# Include in web.config File

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to know whether there is another way to include external files in web.config apart from `configSource="Source"`.

The reason why I am asking is, I am working with UrlRewriter.net module.

```
<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
```

So I did this to seperate the file from web.config for a clean view and edit.

```
<rewriter configSource="rewriter.xml" />
```

So I have a external file where I store rewriter rules.

But I also want to break `rewriter.xml` into separate files.I tried `include` but it says it was not allowed.

Thanks..

Comment: +1. We have URL rewriting all in one massive file (rewriter.config). Would also like to know if it can be split up.

Comment: on one hand though, it kind of makes sense to have it in one file - because URL rewriting is application-wide. splitting it up and changing one of the files, it affects the routes on other files. so unless you're careful it could have undesired effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are splitting the files for maintainability, you might just want to use a post-build process to merge them when you run the application.

Comment: Well it seems a good answer. How do you automate that? Can you append a sample code or something to your answer.